# Fill the word document template with a data from sql database

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-template

Any ideas how to get data automatically from database in new document from word template?

In word document,  Some fields will be master data from database and readonly

Is it possible?  Appreciate any possible solution

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve this but you have to configure it which required little effort.You can use data from an external source in the body of a Microsoft Word 2013 document by using a combination of Microsoft SharePoint external data columns and Word content controls.

- you have to configure BCS
- configure secure store service
- create an external data column(which pulls the data from sql and insert it in word)

Read this kb from MSFT for complete steps:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-external-data-columns-in-a-Word-document-bf0eca47-3ee6-42d3-bafa-2bdc7abeccb7